# Verifying a JWT using the public key with C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, jwt

I am building a React app backed by Azure functions written in C#. I've implemented JWT authentication via Userfront which is working fine on the front end but I'm struggling to verify the token using the public key in the functions.

I've tried numerous approaches, [JWT-DotNet](https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt) being the most recent but to no avail.

Can anyone please provide a working code example?

Here is what I have currently (which errors when creating the new RS256Algorithm with "Cannot find the requested object."):

```
var headers = req.Headers;
if (!headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var tokenHeader))
   return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden);

var token = tokenHeader[0].Replace("Bearer ", "");

var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Userfront_PublicKey"));

var urlEncoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();
var publicKey = urlEncoder.Encode(plainTextBytes);

try
{
   IJsonSerializer serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
   var provider = new UtcDateTimeProvider();
   IJwtValidator validator = new JwtValidator(serializer, provider);
   IJwtAlgorithm algorithm = new RS256Algorithm(new X509Certificate2(plainTextBytes));
   IJwtDecoder decoder = new JwtDecoder(serializer, validator, urlEncoder,algorithm);

   var json = decoder.Decode(token[0], publicKey, verify: true);
}
catch (TokenExpiredException)
   ...
catch (SignatureVerificationException)
   ...
```

Comment: You made sure to strip the "Bearer " text from the Authorization header first, right? :)

Comment: Good spot! Thanks. I didn't, which would have caused me an issue down the line. Same error still currently occurs though :(

Comment: hmm... it's an interesting scenario.. I can't tell from your question whether it is your actual intention (actual project scope) to do this token verification work in an azure function, or whether this is an XY Problem - that you're asking for help on a custom implementation of what is otherwise setup and configured and handled in app service and middleware frameworks....  though, that may be dependent on what service it is that triggers the function..

Comment: Thanks, @BrettCaswell. It's really that with the current setup, Azure functions are called directly from the React App, so ideally, I'd like to stick with this. According to the Userfront docs, it's possible using JWT DotNet but they don't actually give an example.

Comment: I would copy and paste the exact text you are trying to decode and put it into https://jwt.io/ and see if it can parse it.

Comment: What is the output of `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Userfront_PublicKey"));`? This is a public key, so there is no risk of sharing it.

Comment: Hi. Looks like you can't create certificate suitable for RS256Algorithm using public key only

Comment: I think this thread might give you some hints about this issue: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40885/public-key-%E2%86%92-certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the environment variable "Userfront_PublicKey" contains a PEM-encoded RSA public key, i.e.:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
(your base64-encoded RSA public key)
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

then I would try the following (not tested, sorry):

```
var headers = req.Headers;
if (!headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var tokenHeader))
    return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden);

var token = tokenHeader[0].Replace("Bearer ", "");

var publicKeyPem = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Userfront_PublicKey");
var publicKey = RSA.Create();
publicKey.ImportFromPem(publicKeyPem);

try
{
    var json = JwtBuilder.Create()
                         .WithAlgorithm(new RS256Algorithm(publicKey))
                         .MustVerifySignature()
                         .Decode(token); 
}
catch (TokenExpiredException)
...
catch (SignatureVerificationException)
...
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I believe it would work but it requires .net core 5 and would mean converting a number of functions, something that would be a bit of a task currently.

Comment: import ???
RS256Algorithm is not found